# Two or more projects in 1 Assembly?

Tags: .net, assemblies

I want 2 or more DLLs in one Assembly. How can I do this in .NET(VS) or is it even possible? thanks..

Comment: why, what problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

[`ILMerge`](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&displaylang=en) would be the first thing to look at. It combines multiple assemblies into a single assembly (note that the core runtime is still required, etc; it isn't a full linker).

Comment: downloaded it but having hard time using it,, heh

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&displaylang=en).

> ILMerge is a utility for merging multiple .NET assemblies into a single .NET assembly. It works on executables and DLLs alike and comes with several options for controlling the processing and format of the output. See the accompanying documentation for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two or more .dlls in the same assembly, but you can have two or more assemblies in one .dll. [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0) is one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile them to *netmodules*, and then link them together with link.exe .

To compile from MSVS, you should edit project files (depends on language), and then use empty C++\CLI project to use link.exe .